# How do I extract a part of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So I am currently on a project and got stuck when I tried to extract data from a certain range of a list.

I have tried searching for some solutions on here but without success.

```py
ascii = [chr(i) for i in range(255)]
# list of ascii, all i want is to extract all digits[0-9] and [+,-] into another variable
a = '0123456789+-'
if any([x in a for x in enumerate(ascii)]):
    ascii = ascii.replace(x, '')
print(ascii)
```

Comment: that is quite the username

Comment: The iterator `enumerate` yield pair `(index, element)`, you thus want to check that `x[0] in a`, or unpack the tuple.